# ASP.net core razor pages and Jquery datatables plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor, datatables

I've been trying to use the jquery datatables plugin on my web page for a while now, but without result. Can someone help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I use an asp.net core razor page.

I've already tried everything. I find a lot of explanation about ASP.net core MVC but not about razor pages about the Jquery datatables plugin.

```
_Layout_Overzicht.cshtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>@ViewData["Title"] - </title>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <!-- bg-primary text-white -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm bg-primary navbar-dark border-bottom box-shadow mb-3 ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-left">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.rectusoft.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/img/rectusoft_logo_trans_wit.png" height="35" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-right">
                <!-- dit is hier de toggle knop als we het scherm verkleinen-->
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-end">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1  items">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " style="margin-left:1em" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light " style="margin-left:1em" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">PLAYER STATISTICS</a>                       
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav> 
</header>

<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>

<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div class="container">
        &copy; 2022  - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
    </div>
</footer>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
</script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js" integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#example").DataTable();
        })
</script>
</body>
</html>'



'Privacy.cshtml
    @page
    @model organizer.Pages.GamesModel
    @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Player Statistics";
    Layout = "_Layout_Overzicht";
}'

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011-04-25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011-07-25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008-12-13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008-12-19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013-03-03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008-10-16</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Donna Snider</td>
        <td>Customer Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011-01-25</td>
        <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

'''

```
'Privacy.cshtml.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using CompleteBootstrapPlugin;
using DataTables;

namespace organizer.Pages
{
public class PrivacyModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<PrivacyModel> _logger;

    public PrivacyModel(ILogger<PrivacyModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
  }
}
```

'''

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Are you facing a specific problem - perhaps with an error message pointing to a specific line of code? What does "without result" really mean, here? (If you have "already tried everything" then there is nothing left to try... Can you be more precise?).

Comment: Small side note: Can you take a look at your formatting? I see you have used three apostrophes in some places - did you mean to use three backticks instead? See [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Your Layout contains multiple duplicated js file, if your `wwwroot/lib` folder contains bootstrap/jquery css/js file, no need use cdn.

2.The js file cannot be used in `<link>` like below, please remove them:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
```

3.The correct order of these js file should be: `jquery.js`,`bootstrap.js`,`jquery.dataTables.js`.

**Two Working Demo Below**

- If your `wwwroot/lib` folder contains bootstrap/jquery css/js file, change your code like below:

  ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
       <title>@ViewData["Title"] - </title>
       <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
   </head>
   <body>
       <header>
           <!-- bg-primary text-white -->
           <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm bg-primary navbar-dark border-bottom box-shadow mb-3 ">
               //...
           </nav>
       </header>
       <div class="container">
           <main role="main" class="pb-3">
               @RenderBody()
           </main>
       </div>
       <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
           <div class="container">
               &copy; 2022  - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
           </div>
       </footer>

       <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
       <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
       <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $("#example").DataTable();
           })
       </script>
   </body>
   </html>
  ```
- If your `wwwroot/lib` does not contain bootstrap/jquery css/js file, change your code like below:

  ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
       <title>@ViewData["Title"] - </title>
       <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
   </head>
   <body>
       <header>
           <!-- bg-primary text-white -->
           <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm bg-primary navbar-dark border-bottom box-shadow mb-3 ">
               //...
           </nav>
       </header>
       <div class="container">
           <main role="main" class="pb-3">
               @RenderBody()
           </main>
       </div>
       <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
           <div class="container">
               &copy; 2022  - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
           </div>
       </footer>

       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js" integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
       <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $("#example").DataTable();
           })
       </script>
   </body>
   </html>
  ```